# Store the output to variable and also show on screen with process substitution

Tags: bash, ssh

I am trying to do SSH to a server and then `su` to run a command. I am getting prompted for the password twice. I am trying to enhance this to load the prompt with some info to make it clear which password is getting prompted.

```
ssh -tq foo@12.13.14.15 'su root -c hostname'
Password:
Password:
foobarzoo
```

I tried to sneak in a few explanatory strings like below:

```
(printf "For User foo enter "; ssh -tq foo@10.11.12.13 'printf "Enter root "; su root -c hostname')
For User foo enter Password:
Enter root Password:
foobarzoo
```

The above command is almost fine, but I am unable to store the command output into a variable and keep displaying the prompts. So I switched the string to stderr(`>&2`). I am unable to get the password prompt for `su`.

```
output=$((printf "For User foo enter " >&2; ssh -tq foo@11.12.13.14 'printf "Enter root " >&2; su root -c hostname') )
For User foo enter Password:
```

Can someone please tell me how to enhance the above command to keep displaying the prompts and store the output of the command(i.e., hostname) into a variable?

**NOTE**: In case you are wondering, This is a legacy system, `sudo` command is not supported.

Comment: Have you tried using an Expect script? It can selectively assign to variables.

Comment: I was trying to avoid it. However, that is my ultimate fallback plan, but I am hoping to have this challenge reviewed with experts if no other option will go with the expected script...

Comment: I was able to get the 2nd prompt, but it is not taking  `correct` the password:


`output=$(printf "Enter foo " ; ssh -q foo@11.12.13.14 "printf 'Enter Root ' >&2 ; su root -c 'hostname'" |tee /dev/tty)` getting `su: Sorry`